# Convert period to first day of month

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to convert a list of periods to the first day of the month. example of period and new output below

```
Period  new_date
DEC-16  01/12/2016
JAN-17  01/01/2017
FEB-17  01/02/2017
```

I have tried a number of things but am getting stuck with differing types. I also want to do it in the most efficient way as its for a fairly large table.

I am doing this in SQL server

Comment: So what's the question here?  Why don't you show us what you've tried and tell us what the results were that you don't like?  You need to ask a specific question.  We're not going to do the work for you.

Comment: This isn't a period, it's just a string. Prepend `01-` to it and cast to date. This assumes that you are using a English locale *and* that you don't care about Y2K problems.

Comment: the question is how do I convert that string to a date.

Comment: I've just answered it below. apologies if it wasn't clear. I've figured it out now though

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my previous answer, I misunderstood.  You want this instead:

```
SELECT [Period], DATEADD(
    Month, 
    CASE LEFT([Period], 3) WHEN 'JAN' THEN 1 WHEN 'FEB' THEN 2 WHEN 'MAR' THEN 3 WHEN 'APR' THEN 4 WHEN 'MAY' THEN 5 WHEN 'JUN' THEN 6 WHEN 'JUL' THEN 7 WHEN 'AUG' THEN 8 WHEN 'SEP' THEN 9 WHEN 'OCT' THEN 10 WHEN 'NOV' THEN 11 WHEN 'DEC' THEN 12 END - 1, 
    DATEADD(Year, CAST(SUBSTRING([Period], 5, 100) as int), '2000-01-01')) AS [new_date]
FROM (
    SELECT 'DEC-16' as [Period]
    UNION ALL SELECT 'JAN-17' AS [Period]
    UNION ALL SELECT 'FEB-17' AS [Period]
) AS [TEST]
```

Comment: What's the point of multiple answers on the same question? If one of them is wrong, you should edit/delete it all together and add new information in it.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
declare @t table(Period varchar(50))
insert into @t VALUES
('DEC-16')
,('JAN-17')
,('FEB-17')


select Period, cast('01-'+Period as date) new_Date 
from @t
```

Answer (score -2):

SELECT DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, cast('1-'+left(period,3)+right(period,3) as date)), 0) AS StartOfMonth from [table_name]